# Issues defining correct importJSON xpath

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I have the following `importJSON` function (taken from [here](https://www.chicagocomputerclasses.com/google-sheets-import-json-importjson-function/)):

```
function IMPORTJSON(url,xpath){
  try{
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var content = res.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(content);
    
    var patharray = xpath.split("/");
    
    for(var i=0;i<patharray.length;i++){
      json = json[patharray[i]];
    }
    
    if(typeof(json) === "undefined"){
      return "Node Not Available";
    } else if(typeof(json) === "object"){
      var tempArr = [];
      
      for(var obj in json){
        tempArr.push([obj,json[obj]]);
      }
      return tempArr;
    } else if(typeof(json) !== "object") {
      return json;
    }
  }
  catch(err){
      return "Error getting data";  
  }
}
```

I am trying to fetch the formatted marketcap from below:

```
{
    "quoteSummary": {
        "result": [
            {
                "price": {
                    "maxAge": 1,
                    "preMarketChange": {},
                    "preMarketSource": "FREE_REALTIME",
                    "postMarketChangePercent": {
                        "raw": 0.00015075946,
                        "fmt": "0.02%"
                    },
                    "regularMarketSource": "FREE_REALTIME",
                    "regularMarketOpen": {
                        "raw": 134.08,
                        "fmt": "134.08"
                    },
                    "strikePrice": {},
                    "openInterest": {},
                    "exchange": "NMS",
                    "volumeAllCurrencies": {},
                    "circulatingSupply": {},
                    "marketCap": {
                        "raw": 2255968796672,
                        "fmt": "2.26T",
                        "longFmt": "2,255,968,796,672.00"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "error": null
    }
}
```

But I don't understand what xpath to use when calling the function. I have tried:

```
quoteSummary/result[0]/price/marketCap/fmt
/quoteSummary/result[0]/price/marketCap/fmt
quoteSummary/result/0/price/marketCap/fmt
/quoteSummary/result/0/price/marketCap/fmt
```

But I either get `Node not Available` or `Error getting data`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Neither a JSON string nor a JavaScript object === XML - Read this: [What is XPATH](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath)

Comment: I'm calling it xpath because this is how the function refers to it. JSON path is the correct term, but that doesn't change the question why the paths that I'm feeding aren't working.

Comment: If I understand what your doing and I'm not sure that I do then I think it's `json.quotesSummary.result[0].marketcap.fmt`

Comment: That indeed was what I was looking for. Thanks!